# Optimizing CPU Usage in Java Regex Matching

Tags: java, regex, performance, cpu-usage

I encountered a performance issue related to regex matching in my Java project, which resulted in high CPU usage. Despite my attempts at regex optimization, I'm still experiencing performance problems, particularly when multiple threads concurrently invoke the code.

For instance, when calling a method that performs regex matching concurrently 100 times, the CPU usage spikes to 90% for a brief period.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
String BUY_PATTERN =".*\\b(purchase)\\b.*";

private static boolean isMatchPattern(String pattern, String text) {
     return text.matches(BUY_PATTERN);
}
```

I would like to reduce the CPU usage during regex matching. Can you provide suggestions for more efficient regex patterns that achieve the same functionality?

Additionally, I came across an article ([link provided](https://medium.com/javarevisited/a-regular-expression-makes-the-cpu-soar-to-100-72036a4b0771)) discussing the impact of backtracking on performance, but I find it challenging to rewrite the regex to minimize backtracking.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: The library implementation is probably fairly well optimized. We may not be able to provide you with drop-in replacements for it that would perform better. The part you can improve is probably your pattern, especially if it uses backtracking. And you have not shared that.

Comment: Why are there two `.*` items in the pattern? The RegEx will have to process the first `.*` which will match the entire string, then the match for the `p` in `purchase` will fail. It will backtrack by one character and the `p` will fail again, and so on. Perhaps changing to a non-greedy initial part (i.e. to `.*?\\b(purchase)\\b.*`) would improve matters. But, I repeat, why are the two `.*` items present.

Comment: Should also get same result without ".*" if you use find not matches - `Pattern.compile("\\b(purchase)\\b").matcher(text).find()` and you can also re-use the Pattern.compile part.

Comment: As @DuncG said, use the right operation, i.e. `find()` instead of abusing `matches()` with expensive `.*` around the pattern. This already avoids backtracking. But you also don’t need capturing groups, so `Pattern.compile("\\bpurchase\\b").matcher(text).find()` will do. Keep in mind that you can keep and reuse the result of `Pattern.compile(…)`, i.e.  instead of storing the pattern string in a `static final` field, store the `Pattern` object, so you’re not repeating the work on every invocation.

Comment: If you want to squeeze out the maximum performance with the reference implementation, use `Pattern.compile("purchase\\b(?<=\\b.{8})")`. Having the literal text at the beginning of the pattern will enable the internal use of the [Boyer–Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm). But avoiding backtracking and reusing the `Pattern` object are more important.

Comment: If you really want to optimize, avoid using regular expressions for such a simple problem.  You could just do this:  `int i = text.indexOf("purchase"); return i >= 0 && (i == 0 || !Character.isLetter(text.charAt(i))) && (i == text.length() - 8 || !Character.isLetter(text.charAt(i + 8)))`.  It may look longer, but regular expressions do a lot of work under the hood and involve a lot more code than this approach.

Comment: @VGR that’s not doing the same. Your variant checks whether the first occurrence of “purchase” is at word boundaries whereas the original code checks whether there is any occurrence of “purchase” at word boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes you can make.

You can greatly reduce the CPU consumption by creating re-usable objects.

```java
public class Example {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bpurchase\\b");
    Matcher matcher;

    private boolean isMatchPattern(String text) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        return matcher.find();
    }
}
```

Behind the scenes, upon each call of `String.matches`, a new `Pattern` and `Matcher` object is created.

To combat this, you can create `Pattern` and `Matcher` fields within your class.
Then, access these fields from within your `isMatchPattern` method.

Furthermore, for the regular expression pattern, there is no need to capture the text "purchase", so you can remove the parentheses.

Additionally, the context of a `Pattern` pattern is non-conforming; it's expected to be anywhere within the text.
As opposed to a `String.matches` call, which requires the entire parameter to match.
So, you don't need the starting and ending `.*`, as they are redundant.

In regard to using an `String.indexOf`, or `String.contains`.

If you require the word-boundary check, then this is somewhat out of the question in terms of an idiomatic approach, as you'd have to make more than one call.

If you don't require the check, then this would be the way to go.

As a final solution, you can create a character array for-loop, which is more or less what the `Matcher` class does.